# MySQL autoincrement value jumps by 2, when I add a transcaction im my php code

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions, auto-increment

I have a table with patients info and another one for their telephone numbers.
The relationship between them, is 1:N  (1 to many).  I put one restriction: I want all patients have at least one telephone number. So, I put a transaction in my code like this.

```
// Beggining of transaction 
mysqli_query($dbc,'begin'); 
$sql1 = "   INSERT INTO  `dental_clinic`.`patient` (`idpatient` ,`surname` ,`name` ,`middle_name` ,`address` , `town`,  `birth_date` , `occupation` , `email` ,`p_comments`)    VALUES (NULL ,  '$surname',  '$name',  '$middle_name',  '$address',  '$town',  '$birth_date',  '$occupation',  '$email', '$other');
        ";
$execute_sql1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1);  
$last_id =  mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

//  Put some variables to the insert queries of telephone.  
$sql2_1 = " INSERT INTO `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone') ";    
$sql2_2 = "INSERT INTO  `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone2')";
$sql2_3 = "INSERT INTO  `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone3')";

// Checking the first field of telephone 
if (!empty($phone)){  
    $execute_sql2_1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2_1);  
} else {
    $execute_sql2_1 = false;  
}

//  Checking the second field of telephone
if (!empty($phone2)){  
    $execute_sql2_2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2_2);  
} else {
    $execute_sql2_2 = true;  
}

//  Checking the third field of telephone
if (!empty($phone3)){   
    $execute_sql2_3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2_3);  
} else {  
    $execute_sql2_3 = true;  
}  

//  Checking the insert commands to execute toggether
if ($execute_sql1 && $execute_sql2_1){  
    if ($execute_sql2_1 && $execute_sql2_2){  
        if ($execute_sql2_1 && $execute_sql2_3){  
            mysqli_query($dbc, 'commit');  
            echo 'The patient personal details inserted succesfully!';  
            echo 'The primary telephone inserted succesfully! ';  
            header("Location: new_medical_history.php");  
        } else {  
            mysqli_query($dbc, 'rollback');  
            echo 'Error, on 3rd phone! ';  
        }  
    } else {  
        mysqli_query($dbc, 'rollback');  
        echo 'Error, on 2nd phone! ';    
    }  
} else {  
    mysqli_query($dbc, 'rollback');  
    echo 'Error, on patient personal details or on primary telephone! ';  
}  

//  Ending connection
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Both tables, `patient` and `telephone` are in the same form.

When I add succesfully a new patient, the autocrement `idpatient` value, jumps by two (1,3,5,7 and so on.) But when I comment out the transaction,

```
 // mysqli_query($dbc,'begin);  
 // mysqli_query($dbc, 'commit');  
 // mysqli_query($dbc, 'rollback');
```

then the autoincrement value goes normal by one (7,8,9,10, .. etc.).

Could you please tell **why this happening**? Is it *something wrong* in my code? I want to **keep the transaction**, so noone of patients will be added without the primary telephone number.

Comment: It would be helpful if the comments weren't actually Greek...

Comment: Seems like a very complicated *and* incomplete way to do user input validation...

Comment: What storage engine do you use?

Comment: Ok, I made the translation to english. I use InnoDB.
I have one form, with one field of each one of table `personal`, and I have 3 fields availiable to add in the `telephone` table.

I don't mind for the momment, to check the validation of data. I'll do that when I solve this problem.

Comment: be aware that mysql not reset auto increment values on rollback, see if the browser is not sending the data twice or you can add your test cases and sql create in this question...

Answer (score 0):

I find your logic hard to follow, so I have rewritten your code using a try-catch, I believe it satisfies the same requirements and is easier to follow.  Does this still cause a jump-by-2?

```
// fixme: consider using prepared statements to avoid sql injection attacks

mysqli_query($dbc,'begin');

try {
    if(!mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `dental_clinic`.`patient` (`idpatient` ,`surname` ,`name` ,`middle_name` ,`address` , `town`,  `birth_date` , `occupation` , `email` ,`p_comments`) VALUES (NULL, '$surname', '$name', '$middle_name', '$address', '$town', '$birth_date', '$occupation', '$email', '$other')")) throw new Exception('Error, on patient personal details!');
    $last_id =  mysqli_insert_id($dbc); 

    if(empty($phone)) throw new Exception('Error, primary phone required!');

    if(!empty($phone) && !mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone')")) throw new Exception('Error, on primary telephone!');
    if(!empty($phone2) && !mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone2')")) throw new Exception('Error, on 2nd phone!');
    if(!empty($phone3) && !mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO `dental_clinic`.`telephone`(`patient_idpatient`, `phone`) VALUES ('$last_id', '$phone3')")) throw new Exception('Error, on 3rd phone!');

    mysqli_query($dbc, 'commit');  

    // these will not be seen if you immediately redirect
    //echo 'The patient personal details inserted succesfully!';  
    //echo 'The primary telephone inserted succesfully! ';  

    header("Location: new_medical_history.php");  
} catch(Exception $e) {
    mysqli_query($dbc, 'rollback');  
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

//  Ending connection
mysqli_close($dbc);
```